# AngularJS: How to hide menu when route receives a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I hide the `menu` element when the route will receive a number?

Example:
First case: if current route is http:base.com/files the menu should hide when the route will change to http:base.com/files/1 (there could be any number value).

Second case: if current route is http:base.com the menu should hide when the route will change to http:base.com/diff/1/2 (there could be any number value).

Third case (similar to second, only the default route is different): if current route is http:base.com/diff the menu should hide when the route will change to http:base.com/diff/1/2 (there could be any number value).

Basically, the route changes when user selects one checkbox from class `files` (it will get only one number), or when the user selects two checkboxes from class `diff` (it will get two numbers /x/y)

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ku6w2vvs/1/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-menu" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click to toggle menu</a>
  <div class="menu" ng-show="collapsed">
    <div class="files">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>first</label>

      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>second</label>
    </div>
    <div class="diff">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>first</label>

      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>second</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if this helps, I have the following `scope` in my `controller`:

```
scope.update_selection = function(updated_file_id){
    selected_count = 0;
    if (scope.is_initial_selection){
        scope.is_initial_selection = false;
        scope.file_map = {};
        scope.file_map[updated_file_id] = true;
    }

    if (scope.number_of_files == 1){
        path = '/files/' + updated_file_id;
        $location.path(path);
    }
    else {
        updated_file_selected = scope.file_map[updated_file_id];
        if (updated_file_selected) {
            //search for the other file
            found = false;
            for (file_id in scope.file_map){
                if (file_id == updated_file_id)
                    continue;

                found = scope.file_map[file_id];
                if (found == true){
                    scope.file_1_id = file_id;
                    scope.file_2_id = updated_file_id;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found){
                scope.file_1_id = updated_file_id;
                return;
            }
        }

        path = '/diff/' + scope.file_1_id + '/' + scope.file_2_id
        $location.path(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which route lib you are using? Use **ng-if="YOUR_FLAG==true"** to hide the menu element. And use **ng-change** on checkbox.

Comment: What do you mean by 'route lib'? Sorry, I just started to implement something with angularjs and I don't have experience with it..

Comment: I didn't get what you are achieving. But updated your fiddle how you can hide the menu elements. Change this based on your requirements.

Comment: Is there any way to add a trigger click event for menu inside `if (scope.number_of_files == 1)`? That statement checks when the route changes

Comment: So when that `if` condition is evaluated I want to add a click trigger on `<a href="#" class="toggle-menu" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click to toggle menu</a>`

Comment: Check updated Fiddle. Use this functionality in your **if (scope.number_of_files == 1)**

Comment: Where is the updated Fiddle?

Comment: Show below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.collapsed = false;
  $scope.selectedObject = {
    'num': 0,
    'item': ''
  };
  $scope.checkValue = function(number, item) {
    $scope.selectedObject.num = parseInt(number);
    $scope.selectedObject.item = item;
  }
  $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
    $scope.collapsed = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu" ng-if="!collapsed" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Click to toggle menu</a>
    <div class="menu" ng-show="collapsed">
      <div class="files" ng-if="selectedObject.num<1">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkValue('files')" />
        <label>first</label>

        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkValue('files')" />
        <label>second</label>
      </div>
      <div class="diffs" ng-if="selectedObject.num<1">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkValue('diffs')" />
        <label>first</label>

        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkValue('diffs')" />
        <label>second</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a partial solution, you must select two checkboxes from `diffs` to hide that menu...